# How to add new key-value pair into dictionary where value is array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have this structure of my dictionary in python:

```
dict={'key1': [['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2']],....}
```

I want to write function for adding new key-value pair. This is the method:

```
def AddNewPair(key, firstArr, secondArr, thirdArr):
     myDict.update({key:[[firstArr],[secondArr],[thirdArr]]});
```

The example of function call is here:

```
AddNewPair("key2",["val1","val2"],["val1","val2"],["val1","val2"]);
```

This function works, but not properly. It adds new key value pair almost as expected, but the value (array of arrays) is wrapped with another unnecessary array. So, the result is this:

```
dict={'key1': [['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2']],'key2': [[['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2'], ['val1','val2']]] }
```

Of course I dont want this wrapped array. Please, can you help me with this? thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're already passing lists, don't wrap them in square brackets again. This is enough:

```
myDict.update({key:[firstArr, secondArr, thirdArr]})
```

Output:

```
{'key1': [['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val2']],
 'key2': [['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val2']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be, using a `defaultdict` will do the charm elegantly. It creates a value
of a specific type and associates it with a key, as soon as a key is requested
that is not already present. If the key is present the existing value is returned
upon 'get item'.

Accordingly in the case below, the member functions `.append()` and `.extend()` may be used, since it is safe to assume that the returned object is a `list`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

myDict = defaultdict(list)

def AddNewPair(Key, Pair):
    myDict[Key].append(Pair)

def AddNewPairList(Key, PairList):
    myDict[Key].extend(PairList)
```